# simple html dom not working

Tags: php, cakephp, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use simple html dom to parse my html data. But whenever i use the below code i get error as :-

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

My code is:-

```
foreach($html->find('div.row') as $val)
        {
            $name = $val->find('h1')->innertext;
            echo $name;
        }
```

But when i use it like this i get the proper result:-

```
foreach($html->find('div.row') as $val)
        {
            foreach($val->find('h1') as $v)
             echo $v->innertext;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find()` method returns an array unless you specify an index as the second argument. Your second piece of code works as it loops through the array and gets the `innertext` of each element in the array, whereas your first piece of code is trying to get the `innertext` property of the actual array.

If you want to get the first (or only) occurrence of `h1` for example, do this:

```
$name = $val->find('h1', 0)->innertext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($elements as $child) {
    echo $child->nodeValue;
}
```